# how to output a score for a word PYTHON

Tags: python, sorting

Hello i have got a program which has all the values assigned to a letter but i cant figure out how to write program to calculate the score of the word using these values

```
import random
import operator

print("welcome to the letter game challenge")
response=input("enter a word")

print(format(response)) # prints the word you have entered


letterpoints = { "E":(1),
                 "A":(2),
                 "R":(3),
                 "I":(4), #values for each number as shown "i" = 4
                 "O":(5),
                 "T":(6),
                 "N":(7),
                 "S":(8), # values for each number again "s" = 4
                 "L":(9),
                 "C":(10),
                 "U":(11),
                 "D":(12),
                 "P":(13),
                 "M":(14),
                 "H":(15),
                 "G":(16),
                 "B":(17),
                 "F":(18),
                 "Y":(19),
                 "W":(20),
                 "K":(21),
                 "V":(22),
                 "X":(23),
                 "Z":(24),
                 "J":(25),
                 "Q":(26),
}

sorted(letterpoints.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True) #sorts lettervalues from high to low
sort = sorted(letterpoints.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True) #sort function
print(letterpoints)# prints values for letters
print("if you wish to see these results from high to low enter sort")
```

cheers.

Comment: would a word like ABE equal 20?

Comment: Can you provide example(s) of what you are trying to do?  And what you have tried in order to accomplish it?

Comment: a example would be car = 15    ( 10 + 2 + 3)

Comment: ABE would equal 20 . thats what im trying to achieve with this program. to convert a word to a value based on the values of each letter above

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import operator
print("welcome to the letter game challenge")
response=input("enter a word:\n")
print(format(response)) # prints the word you have entered


letterpoints = { "E":(1),
                 "A":(2),
                 "R":(3),
                 "I":(4),#values for each number as shown "i" = 4
                 "O":(5),
                 "T":(6),
                 "N":(7),
                 "S":(8),# values for each number again "s" = 4
                 "L":(9),
                 "C":(10),
                 "U":(11),
                 "D":(12),
                 "P":(13),
                 "M":(14),
                 "H":(15),
                 "G":(16),
                 "B":(17),
                 "F":(18),
                 "Y":(19),
                 "W":(20),
                 "K":(21),
                 "V":(22),
                 "X":(23),
                 "Z":(24),
                 "J":(25),
                 "Q":(26),
}

response = response.upper()
total = 0
for letter in response:
    total += letterpoints.get(letter)

print('your score is {}'.format(total))
```

will work fine if there are no spaces or any characters that are not found in your dictionary else you'll get a `TypErrror`

Comment: Hi @henchness if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This works also if the answer contains non-letter characters (such characters get the score of 0 in the sum):

```
score = sum(letterpoints.get(c, 0) for c in response.upper())
```